# Extract data based on value in previous rows

Tags: python, database, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I received an Excel file with ~60K rows of data that contain information on user interactions with a text messaging application. A simpler example of the data looks as follows:
[image: Example of Data]

I need to extract information based on the response to a question asked in a previous row for each unique User ID. For example if there is an outgoing message: “How many days did ago did you start to feel sick?” and an incoming message that says “3”, I want to create a variable “Sick_Start_Date” for each User ID that says they got sick and subtract 3 from the date of their response to the question. In the example above, it would be 7/11/2017.
I can do this with some formula brute force in Excel, but I imagine there might be a better more “QA-able” way to analyze data that is structured this way. 
Other complexities to consider:

- If a user responds to a message within milliseconds, the data file
  often does not get the order right – it may record two outgoing
  messages and then an incoming message even though it’s clear that the
  incoming message occurred in between the two outgoing messages
- Users don’t always respond and multiple outgoing messages are sent

Comment: It is better to provide a sample data under python structure and show your expected out put for it

Comment: Also provide an example of code you have tried and its result.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I was actually looking for an approach for a type of data more than anything else, but I have since resolved it in a somewhat unelegant, part-manual process!